# Nested IF statements with AND in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I have a column (C) in Excel that looks like this:
[image: columns]

I want the bottom cell (currently green and displaying 1) to: 
display 2 if sum of c2:c14 = 13 and c16 = 1
display 1 if sum of c2:c14 >= 7 and c16 = 1
else display 0

This is what I have and it is saying it is an invalid formula, which I am sure it is, I just can't work out where I have gone wrong...

```
=IF(AND(SUM(C2:C14=13,C16=1),2)),IF(AND(SUM(C2:C14)>=7,C16=1,1),0)
```

Anyone able to help?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just had the parenthesis in the wrong place :)

`=IF(AND(SUM(C2:C14)=13,C16=1),2,IF(AND(SUM(C2:C14)>=7,C16=1),1,0))`

This can be checked by ensuring that each function has a closing parens immediately after the arguments are entered. For example, in `SUM(C2:C14=13,` the `SUM` function only takes range references as arguments, so a closing parens is needed directly after the `C14`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew it would be something like that, I just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntax errors.

```
AND(SUM(C2:C14=13,C16=1))
```

Should be

```
AND(SUM(C2:C14)=13,C16=1))
```

you don't want to evaluate anything inside of the sum.

The 2 should be outside of your AND:

```
IF (AND(SUM(C2:C14)=13,C16=1),2,...)
```

Your second if statement should be nested in the first do it acts like an *if else* statement, and again your desired result of 1 should be outside of your AND.

This could work:

```
=IF(AND(SUM(C2:C14)=13,C16=1),2,IF(AND(SUM(C2:C14)>=7,C16=1),1,0))
```